# Palantir Foundry Metric Widget - how to add reactive filter

Tags: widget, palantir-foundry

How do I create a Metric Widget that counts a field but I want it limited based on a filter I've created.  In other words my filter widget should change how the numbers of my metric report.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a few assumptions from your question, namely that you're referring to a "Metrics Widget" within the context of a Workshop application.

Metric widgets are display-only, so they're going to show whatever the value of accompanying Variable (numeric, string, date, or timestamp).

Filters operate on Object Set variables, so to have a metric widget respond to a Filter, you'll need something like:

`[o] Starting Object Set` (Object Set Variable) -> `[f] Filter List Output` (Filter Variable) -> `[o] Filtered Object Set` (Object Set Variable with Filter Variable applied) -> `[n] Numeric Metric Calculation` (Object Set Aggregation calculation)

With this setup, changing the values in the Filter List widget will update the `[o] Filtered Object Set` variable, which will in turn update the numeric variable value and then the Metric Widget display will update.